# How to fix error: "The method 'execute' isn't defined for the type 'PostgrestFilterBuilder'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to create a login page for an app that's linked to a **supabase database** but I'm getting an error for the user authentication method.

**Error**

- login_page.dart

> The method 'execute' isn't defined for the type
> 'PostgrestFilterBuilder', dart(undefined_method) [Ln 31, Col 10] Try
> correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
> method named 'execute'.

**Login Page:**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class CustomLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomLoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomLoginPageState createState() => _CustomLoginPageState();
}

class _CustomLoginPageState extends State<CustomLoginPage> {
  late final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  late final TextEditingController _lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  late  final TextEditingController _idNumberController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  Future<void> _signIn() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    final client = Supabase.instance.client;
    final response = await client
        .from('user_profile')
        .select()
        .eq('first_name', _firstNameController.text.trim())
        .eq('last_name', _lastNameController.text.trim())
        .eq('id_number', _idNumberController.text.trim())
        .execute();

    if (response.error != null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Login failed: ${response.error?.message}'),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      final data = response.data;
      if (data != null && data.isNotEmpty) {
        // Handle successful authentication.
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/account');
      } else {
        // Handle user not found.
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('User not found. Please check your credentials.'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _firstNameController.dispose();
    _lastNameController.dispose();
    _idNumberController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Custom Sign In')),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: _firstNameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _lastNameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last Name'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _idNumberController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'ID Number'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _signIn,
            child: Text(_isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Sign In'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Main file:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/login.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

//void main() => runApp(MyApp());
void main() async {
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://mtngkmicxfgticmpfrxi.supabase.co',
    anonKey:
        'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6Im10bmdrbWljeGZndGljbXBmcnhpIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDc0MTAwMTgsImV4cCI6MjAyMjk4NjAxOH0.GaBRK6gZqJoFeG43RmVJSH34AQNzb76x2WcOilO4SS0',
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Specify a brightness that matches the color scheme
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.blue,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          brightness:
              Brightness.dark, // Make sure this matches the above brightness
        ).copyWith(
          secondary: Colors.blue,
        ),
        // Define the default font family.
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        // Define the default TextTheme.
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'),
        ),
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

The method I had originally tried was this, but I just got another error related to the from command for this:

```
final response = await supabase
  .from('your_table')
  .select()
  .eq('column_name', 'value')
  .execute();
```

Comment: I am curious to hear why you thought you needed to write `.execute()` at the end of your query. Was it suggested by chatGPT or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the `execute()` method doesn't exist on the `PostgrestFilterBuilder` class.

And by checking the Supabase documentation and the package code the `PostgrestFilterBuilder` is already a `Future` which you can simply `await` to finish your query. So, the correction would be to simply remove the `.execute()` call as follows:

```dart
final response = await client
        .from('user_profile')
        .select()
        .eq('first_name', _firstNameController.text.trim())
        .eq('last_name', _lastNameController.text.trim())
        .eq('id_number', _idNumberController.text.trim())
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:

Also, based on the documentation, in your case, the `response` will be an object of type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` and it won't have `.error` or `.data` properties. The `response` is the result of the query.

In that case, you might want to rewrite your code as this:

```dart
Future<void> _signIn() async {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });
  
  final client = Supabase.instance.client;

  try {
    final response = await client
        .from('user_profile')
        .select()
        .eq('first_name', _firstNameController.text.trim())
        .eq('last_name', _lastNameController.text.trim())
        .eq('id_number', _idNumberController.text.trim());

    if (response.isNotEmpty) {
      // Handle successful authentication.
      if (context.mounted) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/account');
      }
    } else {
      // Handle user not found.
      if (context.mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('User not found. Please check your credentials.'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    if (context.mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Login failed: ${err.toString()}'),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  if (context.mounted) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sreelal, I've taken your advice and changed my code now, but I've run into another problem, where it's saying 'User not found. Please check credentials.' although the credentials used is for user in the profiles user_profiles table.  Is this because response of the query is a list or something else? I've also tried adding the .single() command and got the error "Login failed: PostgrestException(message: JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned, code: PGRST116, details: The result contains 0 rows, hint: null)"

Comment: Seems like the the response contains zero rows. Can you double check your database table `user_profile` has at least one row satisfying the conditions mentioned? I mean, `first_name`, `last_name` and `id_number` each equals to whatever you're passing from the `TextEditingController`s?